# SshConnectionException from SshNet in C#

Tags: c#, ssh, scp

From my script trying to connect to the unix server to download a file but getting below error..

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException : Client not connected.

I can connect properly to that server from WinScp by using the same credentials.

Not sure what's going wrong here. Any idea/pointer ?

**Code**

```
using (var client = new ScpClient(Config.UnixServer, Config.UnixUsername, Config.UnixPassword))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.Upload(new FileInfo(fileUpload), fileName);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

**Error**

```
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException : Client not connected.
at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

[WinSCP Session Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adhvdi5llq3tk53/20170914AUTO-user%40host.log?dl=0)

Comment: Are youe `Config` settings set correctly?

Comment: Yes, I debug the code and getting the values (server, username, password) correctly.

Comment: Show us WinSCP log file.

Comment: How to check WinSCP log ?

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging

Comment: Updated the question with WinSCP log. Not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Not XML log. Session log.

Comment: Please find the log file from below link.Let me know if face issues to access it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/adhvdi5llq3tk53/20170914AUTO-user%40host.log?dl=0

Comment: With WinSCP, you are using SFTP protocol. Do you have any reason no to do the same with SSH.NET? Why do you use SCP?

Comment: I can try to do it in SFTP. Got into it while fixing a bug.

Comment: Whats the advantage SFTP over SCP ?

Comment: @Lee If you want an answer, you will have to provide the information I've asked the OP for. Actually, if you have this problem, I suggest you better start your own question.

Comment: exactly the same problem. No new topic needed.

Comment: So do you actually know that the answer is **"SFTP"**, but you just want to get this posted as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session log shows that WinSCP is using the sftp protocol (WinSCP supports both scp and sftp protocols). Not all sftp servers will accept scp connections. Switch to the `SftpClient` class and use the `UploadFile` method.

I also suspect you meant to call `OpenRead()` on your `FileInfo` instance to get a stream.

```
using (var client = new SftpClient(Config.UnixServer, Config.UnixUsername, Config.UnixPassword))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.UploadFile(new FileInfo(fileUpload).OpenRead(), fileName);
    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps?

Maybe something to do with unix paths? Check `client.RemotePathTransformation = RemotePathTransformation.ShellQuote`;

Have quick read [here](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/wiki/ScpClient:-Remote-path-transformation)

> By default, SSH.NET applies a simple quoting mechanism for remote
>   paths in ScpClient. More precisely, any remote path is enclosed in
>   double quotes before it is passed to the scp command on the remote
>   host.

Comment: The problems happens while connecting, long before any paths are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the trust isn't there?  In the original logs, OP has this:
2017-09-14 09:10:17.495 Host key matches cached key.

The github page: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET
has information about how to establish an expected fingerprint.

The other issue I run into is when a server has a white list of IP addresses and the server is on it, but my test environment is not.

@Lee, the log from the application performing the connection is most helpful in figuring out these kinds of things, as Martin has pointed out.

Comment: SSH.NET does does bother with hostkey verification.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Renci reference lib will solved the issues.